# How to Extract the variable values from terraform variables.tf file using PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-powershell

I have a variables.tf file which contains all the project variables and im trying to fetch a variable values using PowerShell.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "products" {
   default = [
     "Product-1",
     "Product-2",
     "Product-3",
     "Product-4"
     ]
}

variable "product_unified_container" {
   default =  [
     "cont-data",
     "cont-data-2"
     ]
}

variable "location" {
  default = "westeurope"
}
```

Using PowerShell i need to be able to fetch the variable values for any variable I want.

Example : the command should give me a array of all the products variables in variables.tf if it has multiple values.

**write-host $product_list**

Product-1

Product-2

Product-3

Product-4

*if the variable has one value then it should give me that value like "location" variable.*

**write-host $deployed_location**

westeurope

Comment: What have you tried so far and what kind of problems did you encounter?

Comment: Also, why do those values have to be read from the tf files?

Comment: @zett42 I have tried to get the same in Bash which is working, but now the requirement is to be done in Powershell.        Bash code is below.

`cat variables.tf | sed '/products/,$!d' | sed '1d;$d' | sed 's|default|allproducts|g' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '`

Comment: @Marko E - I need this values for further Automation Work which is out of terraform deployments.

Comment: Well, you might as well use the `TF_VAR_<varname>` option for that, i.e., set them as env vars and pull the value from there. Other approach I would suggest is to define outputs for the Terraform part of the code and fetch the values with `terraform output`.

Comment: @Automation-Developer I would consider fetching the values you need out of `state` (the record of what's been created) rather than the static code files.

Comment: As I need these variables for another script using the terraform output of state file data will create a dependency on terraform execution for every new change in Variables.tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by below approach hope this will help someone with similar requirement.
Following Command will fetch any variable values present in variables.tf file, in this case ***variable "products"*** and assign it to another array variable.

```
$product_list = (Get-Content "variables.tf" -Raw) | Foreach-Object {
                $_ -replace '(?s)^.*products', '' `
                -replace '(?s)variable.+' `
                -replace '[\[\],"{}]+' `
                -replace ("default =","") | Where { $_ -ne "" } | ForEach { $_.Replace(" ","") } | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
                }

foreach ( $Each_Product in $product_list.Split("`n")) {
    write-host "Each Product Name : "$Each_Product
}

Output : 
    Each Product Name : Product-1
    Each Product Name : Product-2
    Each Product Name : Product-3
    Each Product Name : Product-4
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through a similar problem so, I can share a way using which you can extract the values.
The problem is it is easy to extract and manipulate values in a json or other format but in tf files it is not the same. So, I have basically used a workaround where I have to set the given file in a structure that the values are filled in one single line
So, variables.tf will look

```
variable "products" {
   default = ["Product-1", "Product-2", "Product-3", "Product-4"]
}

variable "product_unified_container" {
   default =  ["cont-data","cont-data-2"]
}

variable "location" {
  default = "westeurope"
}
```

Next comes the PS code to extract the values of variables-

```
$paramsArray = @()
[system.array]$params = Select-String -Path "variables.tf" -Pattern "default =" -SimpleMatch
if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Params)))
        {
            [system.array]$paramsStrings =  $params -split {$_ -eq "="}

            foreach ($paramString in $paramsStrings)
            {
             
                if (($paramString -match "TF-Template") -or ($paramString -match "tf:"))
                    {
                       #Write-Output $paramString
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      If ($paramsArray -notcontains $paramString)
                      {
                        $paramsArray+=$paramString
                      }
                    }
            }
        }

write-host $paramsArray
```

The output generated is-
[image]

Since this is an array you can iterate and use it later in the script.